# Are bit-wise operations common and useful in real-life programming?

Tags: algorithm, binary

I often bump into interview questions involving a sorted/unsorted array and they ask you to find some sort of property of this array. For example [finding the number that appears odd number of times in an array](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-number-occurring-odd-number-of-times/), or [find the missing number in an unsorted array of size one million](http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Given-an-array-of-a-999-999-numbers-from-1-to-a-1-000-000-there-s-one-number-missing-The-array-is-not-sorted-and-you-ca-QTN_414872.htm). Often the question post additional constraints such as O(n) runtime complexity, or O(1) space complexity. 
Both of these problems can be solved pretty efficiently using bit-wise manipulations. Of course these are not all, there's a whole ton of questions like these.

To me bit-wise programming seems to be more like hack or intuition based, because it works in binary not decimals. Being a college student with not much real life programming experience at all, I'm curious if questions of this type are actually popular at all in real work, or are they just brain twisters interviewers use to select the smartest candidate. 
If they are indeed useful, in what kind of scenarios are they actually applicable?

Comment: Specifying binary options (e.g. turn an option on/off) is the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: @nhahtdh to be specific, XOR are the most popular binary operator I've seen so far, and I don't understand why they always come in handy in solving problems

Comment: If you are working on an implementation of an algorithm or implement some library, then you would see the bitwise operators quite a bit. Not so much if you are working a level beyond it (reusing library).

Answer (score 3):

> Are bit-wise operations common and useful in real-life programming?

The commonality or applicability depends on the problem in hand.

Some real-life projects do benefit from bit-wise operations.

Some examples:

1. You're setting individual pixels on the screen by directly manipulating the video memory, in which every pixel's color is represented by 1 or 4 bits. So, in every byte you can have packed 8 or 2 pixels and you need to separate them. Basically, your hardware dictates the use of bit-wise operations.
2. You're dealing with some kind of file format (e.g. [GIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format)) or network protocol that uses individual bits or groups of bits to represent pieces of information. Your data dictates the use of bit-wise operations.
3. You need to compute some kind of [checksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum) (possibly, [parity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit) or [CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check)) or [hash value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_value) and some of the most applicable algorithms do this by manipulating with bits.
4. You're implementing (or using) an [arbitrary-precision arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary_precision) library.
5. You're implementing [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) and you naturally need to [reverse bits in an integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_reversal) or simulate propagation of carry in the opposite direction when adding. The nature of the algorithm requires some bit-wise operations.
6. You're short of space and need to use as little memory as possible and you squeeze multiple bit values and groups of bits into entire bytes, words, double words and quad words. You choose to use bit-wise operations to save space.
7. Branches/jumps on your CPU are costly and you want to improve performance by implementing your code as a series of instructions without any branches and bit-wise instructions can help. The simplest example here would be choosing the minimum (or maximum) integer value out of two. The most natural way of implementing it is with some kind of `if` statement, which ultimately involves comparison and branching. You choose to use bit-wise operations to improve speed.
8. Your CPU supports floating point arithmetic but calculating something like square root is a slow operation and you instead [simulate it using a few fast and simple integer and floating operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root). Same here, you benefit from manipulating with the bit representation of the floating point format.
9. You're emulating a CPU or an entire computer and you need to manipulate individual bits (or groups of bits) when decoding instructions, when accessing parts of CPU or hardware registers, when simply emulating bit-wise instructions like `OR`, `AND`, `XOR`, `NOT`, etc. Your problem flat out requires bit-wise instructions.
10. You're explaining bit-wise algorithms or tricks or something that needs bit-wise operations to someone else on the web (e.g. here) or in a book. :)

I've personally done all of the above and more in the past 20 years. YMMV, though.

Comment: FWIW, #6 often comes into play when stashing multiple checkbox values from a web page into a single int32 database field...

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it is very useful when you are aiming for speed and efficiency for large datasets.

I use bit vectors a lot in order to represent very large sets, which makes the storage very efficient and operations such as comparisons and combinations very fast. I have also found that bit matrices are very useful for the same reasons, for example finding intersections of a large number of large binary matrices. Using binary masks to specify subsets is also very useful, for example Matlab and Python's Numpy/Scipy use binary masks (essentially binary matrices) to select subsets of elements from matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Using Bitwise Operations is strictly Dependent on your main concerns.

I was once asked to solve a problem to find the all combinations of numbers which don't

have a  repeating digit within them , which are of form N*i, for a given i.

I suddenly made use of bitwise operations and generated all the numbers exactly with better

time , But to my surprise I was asked to rewrite and code with the no use of the Bitwise

Operators , as people find no readability with that , the code which many people has to use

in further . So, If performance is your concern  go for Bitwise .

If readability is your concern reduce their use.

If you want both at time , you need to follow a good style of writing code with bitwise

operators in a way it was readable or understandable .

Answer (score 0):

Although you can often "avoid it" in user-level code if you really don't care for it, it can be useful for cases where memory consumption is a big issue.  Bit operations are often times needed, or even required when dealing with hardware devices or embedded programming in general.

It's common to have I/O registers with many different configuration options addressable through various flag-style bit combinations.  Or for small embedded devices where memory is extremely constrained relative to modern PC RAM sizes you may be used to in your normal work.

It's also very handy for some optimizations in hot code, where you want to use a branch-free implementation of something that could be expressed with conditional code, but need quicker run-time performance.  For example, finding the nearest power of 2 to a given integer can be implemented quite efficiently on some processors using bit hacks over more common solutions.

There is a great book called "Hacker's Delight" Henry S. Warren Jr. that is filled with very useful functions for a wide variety of problems that occur in "real world" code.  There are also a number of online documents with similar things.

A famous document from the MIT AI lab in the 1970s known as [HAKMEM](http://www.inwap.com/pdp10/hbaker/hakmem/hacks.html) is another example.